# Is the name Asma halal for baby girl?

Tags: halal-haram, naming

I really like that name Asma /Esma/, but as far as I know that is one of names of Allah - Asma-ul-Husna. So I would really like to know if it is halal to give that name to a baby girl?

Answer (score 7):

"Asma" means "names" in Arabic; it's not one of the names of Allah (SWT). In fact [Abu Bakr's (RA) daughter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asm%C4%81%27_bint_Abi_Bakr) was named Asma.

"Asma-ul Husna" means "The Beautiful names"

Comment: when I checked the meaning of Asma it came as "supreme" so I thought if it is right to call a baby that way. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

The name Asma' or اسماء  doesn't appear to be a haram name for humans. Besides, I can explain about its meaning that this name "Asma, Asmaa, Asmaa'" looks as the plural form of Esm اسم  which means name(s). as a result, I think it can be Okay and suitable and permissible for you in order to using such a name. you said it is a name of Allah? If I am not wrong, Asma'can be relevance with Asma'al-Hosna' ,  not as a direct name of Allah. Although I've heard that using Allah's names would be Okay in some conditions (if we observe them, may be intentions, and some other conditions that I am not aware about them at the moment). As a result, it is a permissible name as I have heard it before as the name of many Muslimahs too.